# Is it possible to change the stack size in Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, crash

I'm having a crash when working with the Unity Editor, and I was asking me if it can be a problem with the stack. Can I increase the stack size in Unity?

Comment: Doubtful.  Anyway, crashes should be reported to Unity Technical Support

Comment: Have you looked at Editor.log, and confirmed that stack issues are a likely culprit?